# How to wait for silent installation of ASP.NET Core 6.0 Runtime

Tags: .net, .net-core, installation

I want to wait until dotnet hosting bundle is installed. Usually there would a some sort of return code:

- 0   -> ok
- < 1 -> error

```
PS D:\app> .\dotnet-hosting-6.0.4-win.exe /install /passive /norestart
```

Msi doesn't exist, is there any other way?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We solved it by running next command in a loop:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

bool found = false;

// 36 * 5s = 180s = 3 minutes 
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
{
  try
  {
    using Process p = new();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SYSTEMROOT")))
    {
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SYSTEMROOT");
    }

    p.StartInfo.FileName = "dotnet";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "--list-runtimes";
    p.Start();

    // additionally we can search for desired runtime
    found = true;
    break;
  }
  catch (Win32Exception)
  {
    // command is not available yet
  }

  Thread.Sleep(5000); 
}
```

Runtimes example:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `Start-Process -Wait` to run the installer and wait for it to finish:

```
Start-Process .\dotnet-hosting-6.0.4-win.exe -ArgumentList "/install /passive /norestart"
```

---

I didn't test it on ASP.NET Core Runtime 6.0 but I had similar problem with installing .NET SDK 6.0. Running in Powershell just this command as described in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net70#install-with-windows-installer):

```
./dotnet-sdk-6.0.403-win-x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart
```

started the installation process but immediately returned to Powershell (the installation continued in the background). It seems that .exe and .msi installers works that way and you need to use `start /wait` in [cmd](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/waiting-for-msiexec-exe-to-finish/) or `Start-Process -Wait` in [Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39149293/350384) to wait in terminal/script for the process installation to finish. Like this:

*Powershell*

```
Start-Process -Wait 'C:\dotnet-sdk-6.0.410-win-x64.exe' -ArgumentList '/install /quiet /norestart';
```

*cmd*

```
start /w C:\dotnet-sdk-6.0.410-win-x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart
```