# How to detect if CMD is running as Administrator/has elevated privileges?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

From inside a batch file, I would like to test whether I'm running with Administrator/elevated privileges.

The username doesn't change when "Run as Administrator" is selected, so that doesn't work.

If there were a universally available command, which has no effect, but requires administrative privileges, then I could run that and check for an error code in order to test for privileges.  So far, I haven't found such a command.  The commands I have found seem to return a single, non-specific error code, which could indicate anything, and they're prone to failure for a variety of reasons.

I only care about Windows 7, though support of earlier operating systems would be nice.

Comment: One hack would to be try to and do `echo > somefile` into a directory that would require admin privs. it'd produce a file as a sideffect, but you could check for collisions and create a unique filename as a workaround.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch script: how to check for admin rights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights)

Comment: [you can find a self-elevating batch here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights/27083926#27083926

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to request Administrator access inside a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file)

Comment: @npocmaka the question you linked is actually the duplicate of this one ;) (2013 vs. 2011)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**ADDENDUM**: For Windows 8 this will not work; see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights#11995662) instead.

---

Found this solution here: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/clevertricks.php

```
AT > NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    ECHO you are Administrator
) ELSE (
    ECHO you are NOT Administrator. Exiting...
    PING 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1
    EXIT /B 1
)
```

Assuming that doesn't work and since we're talking Win7 you could use the following in Powershell if that's suitable:

```
$principal = new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
$principal.IsInRole([System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
```

If not (and probably not, since you explicitly proposed batch files) then you could write the above in .NET and return an exit code from an exe based on the result for your batch file to use.

Comment: The AT command is perfect!  Your Google-fu is superior to my Google-fu.  ;-)

Comment: +1 @Rushyo, I extended your solution a bit and posted it here since that's the one I originally came across.  Thanks!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights/8995407#8995407

Comment: `AT` doesn't work on Windows 8, but I've found a better solution. I've posted it as an answer on another question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights#11995662.

Comment: I recommend whoami /groups | findstr /b BUILTIN\Admin | findstr /c:"Enabled group" && echo "I have a admin!" - work on 95, 98, 2000, xp, vista, 7, 8! (From comment "I like Rushyo's sugesstion of using AT ...")

Comment: barwnikk, whoami /groups has an edge case where you get the wrong information.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights/30921854#30921854

Comment: I like the `ping` to replace missing `sleep` :)

Comment: put the scripts into a cmd text file, run as normal, then as admin, both produced the same message "you are NOT Administrator. Exiting..."

Comment: in win 10 for me this produced "you are NOT administrator" in both regular and elevated cmd prompt.  This option did work: `@echo off

whoami /groups | find "S-1-16-12288" > nul

if %errorlevel% == 0 (
 echo Welcome, Admin
) else (
 echo Get lost, User
)`

Comment: @barwnikk this might work on english Windows installations. For example, here, you'd have to findstr for something like `VORDEFINIERT\Administratoren` and `Aktivierte Gruppe`. (not tested, though)

Comment: Commad AT is deprecated in windows 10. Use command 'net session', see posts bellows.

Comment: For PowerShell you can also used the "#Requires -RunAsAdministrator" at the beginning of your script to require elevation.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work when elevated using the incredibly useful [gsudo](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo}.

Comment: If anyone reading this has the rep for a 1-character edit, there's now an https version of the URL linked to in this answer.

Comment: Switched to HTTPS. Ta!

Answer (score 186):

This trick only requires one command: type `net session` into the command prompt.

If you are **NOT an admin**, you get an access is denied message.

```
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

If you **ARE an admin**, you get a different message, the most common being:

```
There are no entries in the list.
```

From [MS Technet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490711(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> Used without parameters, net session displays information about all
> sessions with the local computer.

Comment: That's functionally identical to Rushyo's answer, which used the AT command.

Comment: On Windows 8.1, this is preferred to AT, as AT is deprecated. Using Rushyo's answer but substituting **AT** with **net session** or **net.exe session** works perfectly for me.

Comment: This seems the easiest way to do this on command prompt (which is different than batch file, though).

Comment: Just prints `There are no entries in the list.` in Windows 10 Pro

Comment: in a batch file use something like that: `net session >nul 2>&1 || (echo not admin&goto :eof)`

Comment: use %errorlevel% to detect... if 0 the script is executing as elevated... if 2 is executing as normal user...

Answer (score 33):

I like Rushyo's suggestion of using AT, but this is another option:

```
whoami /groups | findstr /b BUILTIN\Administrators | findstr /c:"Enabled group" && goto :isadministrator
```

This approach would also allow you to distinguish between a non-administrator and a non-elevated administrator if you wanted to.  Non-elevated administrators still have BUILTIN\Administrators in the group list but it is not enabled.

However, this will not work on some non-English language systems.  Instead, try

```
whoami /groups | findstr /c:" S-1-5-32-544 " | findstr /c:" Enabled group" && goto :isadministrator
```

(This should work on Windows 7 but I'm not sure about earlier versions.)

Comment: In polish version, I have: BUILTIN\Administratorzy, so, I recommend: whoami /groups | findstr /b BUILTIN\Admin | findstr /c:"Enabled group" && goto :isadministrator

Comment: @barwnikk, I recommend `whoami/groups` and then scanning the lines manually. Wouldn't take too long and the command fits in your brain.

Comment: @Pacerier: the point of the question is to detect elevation *in a batch file*.  If a person is at the command line, all they need do is look at the window title, which always starts "Administrator:" if you are elevated.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, Wow didn't realize that. Does the "Administrator" title appear for all versions of windows?

Comment: @Pacerier: all current versions (Vista onwards).

Comment: whoami /groups has an edge case where you get the wrong information.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights/30921854#30921854

Comment: @zumalifeguard: when I tested it, `whoami /groups` gave me the right information: that the group is present but disabled.  My code checks that the group is enabled, so it shouldn't give you the wrong answer in your scenario.

Comment: I like this because it doesn't cause an error if user is not an admin. In a Visual Studio build event if there is an errorlevel the build will fail. This will code allows the build to proceed if user is not an admin.

Comment: Be aware that if you have a large list of groups this is too slow to be feasible. I just tried it on one machine (Win7 on a domain) and it took almost 30 seconds to gather the group list.

Answer (score 33):

Pretty much what others have put before, but as a one liner that can be put at the beginning of a batch command.  (Well, usually after @echo off.)

```
net.exe session 1>NUL 2>NUL || (Echo This script requires elevated rights. & Exit /b 1)
```

Comment: This is the up to date version and it hides the irrelevant output from net.exe nicely

Comment: Works well on Windows 10.

Comment: Worked great, just tweaked the end to & Timeout /t 10 & Exit /b 1) so that in a batch file the window doesn't instantly disappear.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to do this on Vista, Win 7 and above is enumerating token groups and looking for the current integrity level (or the administrators sid, if only group memberhip is important):

Check if we are running elevated:

```
whoami /groups | find "S-1-16-12288" && Echo I am running elevated, so I must be an admin anyway ;-)
```

Check if we belong to local administrators:

```
whoami /groups | find "S-1-5-32-544" && Echo I am a local admin
```

Check if we belong to domain admins:

```
whoami /groups | find "-512 " && Echo I am a domain admin
```

The following article lists the integrity level SIDs windows uses: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx

Comment: whoami /groups has an edge case where you get the wrong information.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights/30921854#30921854

Answer (score 10):

the solution:

```
at >nul
if %ErrorLevel% equ 0 ( echo Administrator ) else ( echo NOT Administrator )
```

does not work under Windows 10

for all versions of Windows can be do so:

```
openfiles >nul 2>&1
if %ErrorLevel% equ 0 ( echo Administrator ) else ( echo NOT Administrator )
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a slight modification of Harry's answer that focuses on elevated status; I'm using this at the start of an install.bat file:

```
set IS_ELEVATED=0
whoami /groups | findstr /b /c:"Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level" | findstr /c:"Enabled group" > nul: && set IS_ELEVATED=1
if %IS_ELEVATED%==0 (
    echo You must run the command prompt as administrator to install.
    exit /b 1
)
```

This definitely worked for me and the principle seems to be sound; from [MSFT's Chris Jackson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2006/10/24/modifying-the-mandatory-integrity-level-for-a-securable-object-in-windows-vista.aspx):

> When you are running elevated, your token contains an ACE called Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level.

Comment: whoami /groups has an edge case where you get the wrong information.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights/30921854#30921854

Answer (score 7):

I read many (most?) of the responses, then developed a bat file that works for me in Win 8.1. Thought I'd share it.

```
setlocal
set runState=user
whoami /groups | findstr /b /c:"Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level" > nul && set runState=admin
whoami /groups | findstr /b /c:"Mandatory Label\System Mandatory Level" > nul && set runState=system
echo Running in state: "%runState%"
if not "%runState%"=="user" goto notUser
  echo Do user stuff...
  goto end
:notUser
if not "%runState%"=="admin" goto notAdmin
  echo Do admin stuff...
  goto end
:notAdmin
if not "%runState%"=="system" goto notSystem
  echo Do admin stuff...
  goto end
:notSystem
echo Do common stuff...
:end
```

Hope someone finds this useful :)

Comment: whoami /groups has an edge case where you get the wrong information.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights/30921854#30921854

Comment: Thank you for this! The other "whoami" solution's didn't work for me on Windows 8.1. This one did.

Answer (score 4):

A "not-a-one-liner" version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/38856823/2193477

```
@echo off
net.exe session 1>NUL 2>NUL || goto :not_admin
echo SUCCESS
goto :eof

:not_admin
echo ERROR: Please run as a local administrator.
exit /b 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running as a user with administrator rights then environment variable SessionName will NOT be defined and you still don't have administrator rights when running a batch file.

You should use "net session" command and look for an error return code of "0" to verify administrator rights.

Example;
 - the first echo statement is the bell character

`net session >nul 2>&1
if not %errorlevel%==0 (echo 
echo  You need to start over and right-click on this file, 
echo  then select "Run as administrator" to be successfull.
echo.&pause&exit)`

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm really late to this party, but here's my one liner to determine admin-hood.

It doesn't rely on error level, just on `systeminfo`:

```
for /f "tokens=1-6" %%a in ('"net user "%username%" | find /i "Local Group Memberships""') do (set admin=yes & if not "%%d" == "*Administrators" (set admin=no) & echo %admin%)
```

It returns either yes or no, depending on the user's admin status...

It also sets the value of the variable "admin" to equal yes or no accordingly.

Comment: This will only work if the user is a direct member of the Administrators local group.  If the user is a member of a domain group (e.g., "Domain Admins") that is a member of the Administrators group, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple method I've used on Windows 7 through Windows 10. Basically, I simply use the "IF EXIST" command to check for the Windows\System32\WDI\LogFiles folder. The WDI folder exists on every install of Windows from at least 7 onward, and it requires admin privileges to access. The WDI folder always has a LogFiles folder inside it. So, running "IF EXIST" on the WDI\LogFiles folder will return true if run as admin, and false if not run as admin. This can be used in a batch file to check privilege level, and branch to whichever commands you desire based on that result.

Here's a brief snippet of example code:

```
IF EXIST %SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\WDI\LOGFILES GOTO GOTADMIN
(Commands for running with normal privileges)

:GOTADMIN
(Commands for running with admin privileges)
```

Keep in mind that this method assumes the default security permissions have not been modified on the WDI folder (which is unlikely to happen in most situations, but please see caveat #2 below). Even in that case, it's simply a matter of modifying the code to check for a different common file/folder that requires admin access (System32\config\SAM may be a good alternate candidate), or you could even create your own specifically for that purpose.

There are two caveats about this method though:

1. Disabling UAC will likely break it through the simple fact that everything would be run as admin anyway.
2. Attempting to open the WDI folder in Windows Explorer and then clicking "Continue" when prompted will add permanent access rights for that user account, thus breaking my method. If this happens, it can be fixed by removing the user account from the WDI folder security permissions. If for any reason the user MUST be able to access the WDI folder with Windows Explorer, then you'd have to modify the code to check a different folder (as mentioned above, creating your own specifically for this purpose may be a good choice).

So, admittedly my method isn't perfect since it can be broken, but it's a relatively quick method that's easy to implement, is equally compatible with all versions of Windows 7, 8 and 10, and provided I stay mindful of the mentioned caveats has been 100% effective for me.

Comment: On Windows 11, I ran most of the previous methods, and none of them work. You method work.

Answer (score 1):

Works for Win7 Enterprise and Win10 Enterprise

```
@if DEFINED SESSIONNAME (
    @echo.
    @echo You must right click to "Run as administrator"
    @echo Try again
    @echo.
    @pause
    @goto :EOF
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, "S-1-5-32-544" that others have suggested is not proof of elevation.

Windows 10 and higher, a language independent approach is:

```
whoami /groups | find "S-1-16-12288"
```

this is the "High Mandatory Level", which is actually escalated.

Regular command prompt:

```
C:\> whoami /groups | find "S-1-16-12288"
C:\>
```

Administrator command prompt:

```
C:\> whoami /groups | find "S-1-16-12288"
Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level                          Label            S-1-16-12288                                                                                                                                                     


C:\>
```

To use in a .bat file:

```
whoami /groups | find "S-1-16-12288" && set ELEVATED=true || set ELEVATED=false
```

You can also use this from powershell:

```
function is_elevated() {
  Param( [String] $ToGroup = "S-1-16-12288" )
  return [bool] ( whoami /groups | select-string $ToGroup )
}
```

for example:

```
PS> cd c:/temp
PS> set-content is-elevated.ps1 "return [bool] ( whoami /groups | sls S-1-16-12288 )"
PS> ./is-elevated.ps1
False
PS> start -verb runas powershell.exe
...
PS C:\Windows\system32> cd \temp
PS C:\temp> ./is-elevated.ps1
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Torin Darkflight,
Your method is the only one that work for me on Windows 11.
Here's an example script expanding on your post:

```
IF EXIST %SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\WDI\LOGFILES GOTO :Running_As_An_Admin
ECHO You are NOT an Administrator. This command requires admin rights. & Echo: & Echo Quitting......
@TIMEOUT /T 10
goto :QUIT
:Running_As_An_Admin
Echo Do Admin stuff here!!!

:QUIT
```