# Elevated Privilege in XP

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-xp, batch-processing, elevated-privileges

Does anyone know how to do this on xp using tha batch command, this will be tested in the limited user.
I have found something and it works fine in W7 but when I tried it on XP it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cls
@echo off


:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    cls
    echo ... restart console with privilege admin ...
    pause>nul
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( 
    echo ... ok jedi ...
    goto gotAdmin 
)

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B
:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could you give us more information ? you can find info on calcs.exe here : http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-caclsexe-to-view-and-manage-windows-acls/

Comment: I don't think the runas verb existed in XP.

Comment: @HarryJohnston The verb did exist, but worked differently, since there was no UAC.

Comment: anyway, I have another issue. We wont longer use this on xp.

Comment: I have another issue that needs to check if the user(limited) did not log in as admin using the elevated privilege then the batch will not execute the program.exe. Else if the user login as an admin in elevated privilege then this will continue the execution of the program.exe, is this possible?

Comment: @CireGarcia: [already asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985755/how-to-detect-if-cmd-is-running-as-administrator-has-elevated-privileges).

Answer (score 2):

[User Account Control](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-user-account-control) (UAC) was introduced with Windows Vista. It's not available in earlier versions like XP.

In XP, when you are member of the Administrators group, you have admin privileges all of the time, so there's no need for elevation. If you're not a member of the Administrators group you need to authenticate as a different user, which can be done via the [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\ADMIN_USER some_command
```

With that said, support for Windows XP  [ended](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx) on April 8 this year, so you shouldn't be using it anymore. In fact, you should have migrated off XP a *long* time ago.

Answer (score 0):

The nir command tools have such a functionality too:

http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/runas.html

```
nircmd runas
```