# Add Windows user from command line

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to add a new Windows user from the command line [using these instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/515175/create-admin-user-from-command-line).  I'm just trying to add a regular user at this time.  The command I'm entering is

`net user /add admin-user admin`

I get the following messages:

> System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied.

I am running this from an admin account, and I'm able to create a user by going through the regular settings screens.  What am I doing wrong?  TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are not running your CMD as admin.

You can check this by typing `net session` as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16285248/4934937).

To run your CMD as admin:

1. Press the windows key
2. Type cmd
3. Right click on the localised name of cmd (command prompt)
4. Click on "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  This worked.  Funny thing is though:  I had to do this even when running from the account I had set up to be an admin account.  Like I said, I could add an account manually with this admin account.  But I had to do the "Run as Administrator" even though I was signed in as an admin-account user.  Strange.  Thx again.

Comment: This is not strange, this is a security feature. The UAC requires to confirm to run the CMD as admin - if it wouldn't ask for this, any program could do administrative stuff on your machine even if it didn't ask for this privilege which would be much more close to a root user on any unix based system. It's kinda annoying, but it could save you from some malicious software or scripts :)