# Batch Script - different when admin or not

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've been trying to copy a file using a script, and I had the following code. It displays as expected when run: C:\Users\Nico\Desktop\Stopthe.scr

If I run it as Administrator, which it needs to work correctly, it displays a different path: C:\Windows\System32\Stopthe.scr

The script is I'm testing is on the desktop.

```
:: don't output the commands that are running to screen
echo OFF
:: label for a goto statement - although not required atm
:start
:: clears the screen
cls
:: variable - path to where script is located
set herePath=%cd%\Stopthe.scr
:: %cd% returns the current directory of where the script is.

echo  %herePath%
echo.

pause
```

I want to locate the path, and it returns the correct path when running normally, but when ran as administrator, it doesn't return the path to the script (but presumably where the cmd.exe is located).

I understood %cd% to return the current directory the script is in, which is what I want.

Comment: may be you need this? ->http://stackoverflow.com/a/28268802/388389

Answer (score 1):

Running a batch script as administrator always defaults the working directory (i.e. `%CD%`) to `C:\Windows\System32`.

The path to where script is located is (including trailing backslash) `%~dp0`, so you could use

```
set "herePath=%~dp0Stopthe.scr"
```

Resource: [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), part *Links relative to the Batch Script*

Comment: +1 for the tip with %~dp0: this is handy in so many situations, and many developers and admins confuse the default path with the programs own path. I also use something similar often in C# programs / perl scripts or else to load files relative to the program`s path. This even works with UNC paths.