# How to test for administrator privileges in an msysgit/Cygwin script?

Tags: windows, bash, command-line, cygwin, msysgit

How do you test if you have administrator privileges in a script for msysgit/Cygwin? On my machine, opening Git Bash as admin and running `whoami` still outputs `James`, not `root`.

I guess you could probably do something like

```
if touch /C/file.txt && rm /C/file.txt; then
    echo 'Admin!'
else
    echo 'Not admin!'
fi
```

but that feels very hackish. Is there any better way to do this?

**edit:** Also tried `id` and `id -G`, but they have the same output for admin and regular terminals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution from [Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights#11995662):

```
if net session &> /dev/null; then
    echo 'Admin!'
else
    echo 'Not admin!'
fi
```