# Get Windows user rights with PHP or with PHP and external application

Tags: php, windows, administrator, admin-rights

I'm working on a Windows tool coded with PHP that proposes different options according to the user rights.

So, the tool needs to know first what are the user rights.
I didn't find any PHP variable providing those information. I've found `accesschk.exe` but I didn't get any useful information.

First, I need to know if the user can install a service. So, I guess that I need to know if he is an administrator. Is there any CLI application that can get the user permissions ?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights

Comment: @Steve This is useful. And I'll do tests with this solution. But is there any external application which is able to clearly say if the user is administrator or not ?