# inconsistent administrator permissions in windows

Tags: windows, cmd, admin

I'm a mac user making my first foray into windows development and I've run into some confusing admin privilege errors. I'm running a Windows 10 install via Bootcamp on my macbook pro that I just set up yesterday (I haven't "activated windows" ie not paid for it, not sure if that would make a difference with my issue). I'm an administrator and also the only user on the system, which I confirmed by first checking through the Settings app, and then by running these commands:

```
C:\Users\will\code\chrome-native-messaging>net user "%username%"
User name                    will
Full Name
Comment
User's comment
Country/region code          000 (System Default)
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never

Password last set            9/26/2016 1:38:13 PM
Password expires             Never
Password changeable          9/26/2016 1:38:13 PM
Password required            No
User may change password     Yes

Workstations allowed         All
Logon script
User profile
Home directory
Last logon                   9/28/2016 1:03:42 PM

Logon hours allowed          All

Local Group Memberships      *Administrators       *Ssh Users
Global Group memberships     *None
The command completed successfully. 



C:\Users\will\code\chrome-native-messaging>net localgroup administrators
Alias name     administrators
Comment        Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the    computer/domain

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator
will
The command completed successfully.
```

However, when I run another command suggested in an SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21295806) to verify my admin status, I get an `access denied` error:

```
C:\Users\will\code\chrome-native-messaging>fsutil dirty query %systemdrive%
Error:  Access is denied.
```

Any pointers on how to successfully run this command are much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Your command prompt is not running with elevated permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you launch the command prompt with `Run as Administrator`?

`fsutil` requires the command prompt to be elevated.  You can check this by seeing if "Administrator: C:...\cmd.exe" is in the command prompt's title bar.

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. For others who might stumble across the same issue, here's how to run the command prompt as an administrator: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx