# Is there a command to check if Git Bash is opened in Administrator mode?

Tags: git, console, git-bash, administrator

Let's say you opened a Git Bash console and used it for a time but you forgot if you opened it as Administrator or not.

Is there a way to check this in the current console, without closing and opening it again?

Comment: Why would you open Git Bash as an administrator in the first place?

Comment: Run `env | grep SESSIONNAME`. If it's run as Administrator, the command returns nothing. If not, it returns `SESSIONNAME=Console`. But this is just what I have observed from tests. I am not sure if this is the difference caused by running as or not as administrator. I have no idea what SESSIONNAME means.

Comment: @ElpieKay you may be right

Comment: @ElpieKay This appears to be true for my Git Bash install as well.

Answer (score 16):

Adapted from the thread on [how to check for admin rights](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4051883/1366033), run the following:

```sh
if [[ $(sfc 2>&1 | tr -d '\0') =~ SCANNOW ]]; then echo Administrator; else echo $USERNAME; fi
```

If you are running `git-bash` as Administrator, it will print `Administrator`, otherwise it will print your username.

Comment: What's `fi` doing?

Comment: `fi` is the end of the `if` block.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29

Answer (score 1):

My PS1 environmental variable looks like this:

```
\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$
```

So off the back of the answer from @daveloyall. I've put this into my .bash_profile

```
if [[ $(sfc 2>&1 | tr -d '\0') =~ SCANNOW ]]; then
    export TITLEPREFIX='ADMIN' 
fi
```

This then prefixes the window title with `ADMIN` if you've opened git-bash as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

A reliable way to check if git-bash on Windows is running as admin privilege:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

net session 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || printf >&2 "error: please run this script as administrator.\n"
```

If you want to take into consideration that there might be a Windows which has no `net` command (I doubt that), you can check for it:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if type -fq net >/dev/null
then
    net session 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || printf >&2 "error: please run this script as administrator.\n"
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try a linux command, like that:

```
whoami
```

This will return your system username

or windows command:

```
ECHO %USERNAME%
```

Comment: But it returns the same result whether you are running git bash as Administrator or not...

Answer (score -4):

Yes, You can check the current username by using this command:

git config user.name

This will return the username and you can know if it is the Administrator.

Comment: This only returns the username but not if this user currently has Administrator access.

Comment: The git user name can be anything. Has nothing to do with windows user or access permissions.