# Command Prompt powershell command to elevate batch file passing arguments

Tags: powershell, cmd, runas, elevation

From cmd I'm using the powershell command to elevate a batch script and pass it arguments. The arguments contain double quotes but I can't figure out why it's not working.

Here's my command:

```
powershell -command "Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\My Path\update.bat' -ArgumentList '\"My File.zip\"'"
```

The above command works fine and my batch script receives the argument in double quotes, but when I change the command to elevate using `-Verb Runas` is where I have the problem (the batch script opens, but immediately closes):

```
powershell -command "Start-Process -Verb Runas -FilePath 'C:\My Path\update.bat' -ArgumentList '\"My File.zip\"'"
```

Comment: Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54658703/6738015), from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54658352/6738015) posed just yesterday, which may help you out!

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you!

Comment: I know, _but sometimes it's good to hear it from somebody other than my therapist!_

Answer (score 0):

Final solution derived from @Compo's response above. This solution worked for me and handles when the batch script's path contains spaces too.

```
set "Args=%*"
net file 1>nul 2>&1 || (powershell -Command ^
Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath '%comspec%' -ArgumentList '/c \""\""%~f0\"" %Args:"=\""%\""'
goto :eof)
```

Comment: Kudos for handling the case where the batch file path has embedded spaces, but this solution still isn't fully robust - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54701990/45375

Comment: @mklement0, I agree. I'm working on a better solution but this at least got me past some of the initial issues I was seeing. I will follow up once I'm finished.

Comment: The [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54701990/45375) is my attempt to create a fully robust solution; I invite you to try it and tell us if there are cases it doesn't handle correctly - I'm happy to amend it, if possible.

Comment: @mkelement0, where were you a day ago?? Worked perfect, thanks you.