# Is there any way to maintain a batch script library?

Tags: batch-file, label, shared-libraries, goto, subroutine

I'm writing a complex batch patch file with generation of other files. I know that batch is not the best for it but I've mostly got it all working. However, there is a headache of keeping all subroutines duplicated in all files if I don't want to make a separate file for each subroutine. My question was whether there is any way of keeping a library file of multiple subroutines and call them somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm going to answer my own question because I managed to get something working.

Lets say you have main.bat and lib.bat files.

Main.bat

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
    SET return=
    SET reference=this is just a reference variable

    CALL lib.bat return "subroutine" "static arg" reference
    IF NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
        ECHO Execution failed - %ERRORLEVEL%
        EXIT /b 1
    )

    ECHO.
    ECHO subroutine return value: "%return%"
    ECHO.

    CALL lib.bat NUL "procedure" "static arg" reference

    ECHO.

    CALL lib.bat return "error" "static arg" reference
    IF NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
        ECHO Execution failed - %ERRORLEVEL%
        EXIT /b 1
    )
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /b 0
```

Lib.bat

```
@ECHO off

::
:: ===================================================================================
:: Library Main Handler
:: ===================================================================================
:: %~1  - [out] - NUL | reference to a return variable
:: %~2  - [in]  - subroutine label to be invoked
:: %~3+ - [in]  - optional arguments to the subroutine
::
:: ERRORLEVEL is passed through to the caller
::

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
    SET callSub=%~2
    SET return=
    SET args=

    IF "%callSub%"=="" (
        ECHO Subroutine label was not provided to the library. 1>&2
        EXIT /b 1
    )

    :buildUpArgumentList
    IF "%~3"=="" GOTO end_buildUpArgumentList
       SET args=%args% "%~3"
    SHIFT /3
    GOTO buildUpArgumentList
    :end_buildUpArgumentList

    IF NOT "%~1"=="NUL" (
        call:%callSub% return %args%
        IF NOT "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="0" (
            EXIT /b !ERRORLEVEL!
        )
    ) ELSE (
        call:%callSub% %args%
        IF NOT "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="0" (
            EXIT /b !ERRORLEVEL!
        )
    )
(
    ENDLOCAL
    IF NOT "%~1"=="NUL" (
        SET %~1=%return%
    )
)
EXIT /b 0

::
:: ===================================================================================
:: Library Subroutine Definitions
:: ===================================================================================
::

:subroutine <r_return> <static> <r_reference>
    SETLOCAL
        ECHO subroutine^<static^>: "%~2"
        ECHO subroutine^<r_reference^>: "!%~3!"
    (
        ENDLOCAL
        SET %~1=subroutine executed OK
    )
EXIT /b 0

:procedure <static> <r_reference>
    SETLOCAL
        ECHO procedure^<static^>: "%~1"
        ECHO procedure^<r_reference^>: "!%~2!"
    ENDLOCAL
EXIT /b 0

:error <r_return> <static> <r_reference>
    SETLOCAL
        ECHO error^<static^>: "%~2"
        EXIT /b 2
        ECHO error^<r_reference^>: "!%~3!"
    (
        ENDLOCAL
        SET %~1=error executed OK
    )
EXIT /b 0
```

Output:

```
subroutine<static>: "static arg"
subroutine<r_reference>: "this is just a reference variable"

subroutine return value: "subroutine executed OK"

procedure<static>: "static arg"
procedure<r_reference>: "this is just a reference variable"

error<static>: "static arg"
Execution failed - 2
```

Some comments:

- The library subroutine invocation is similar to a regular function signature:  () but without parentheses.
- You will notice that the library code checks for NUL being passed. If that is the case, return value is neither passed to the subroutine nor is it returned back.
- The subroutine arguments support n-number of arguments.
- The library supports error level pass-through.
- If a provided subroutine label does not exist within the library, batch will return ERRORLEVEL=1 and a message "The system cannot find the batch label specified - [label]."

Additional thoughts:

- I am relatively new to batch scripting so not everything is perfect.
- This was done in ~1hr and I'm sure its missing some stuff!
- Should some escaping be performed when constructing the arguments array (i.e., quotes)?

Any other comments are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach is to use the following trick:

1. Enclose the code that call the library functions between parentheses.
2. At beginning of the parentheses rename the current Batch file to other name, and rename the library file as the current Batch file.
3. Now you can call any library function in the same way as before.
4. Before parentheses ends, rename the files back to original names.

For example:

```
(
rem Switch the active context to the library file:
ren "%~0" main.bat
ren libraryFile.bat "%~0"
rem From this line on you may call any function in the library file, for example:
call :FUNCTION

rem Switch the context back to original file
ren "%~0" libraryFile.bat
ren main.bat "%~0"
)
```

For further details, see: 
[How to package all my functions in a batch file as a seperate file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742150/how-to-package-all-my-functions-in-a-batch-file-as-a-seperate-file/18751689#18751689)

Comment: Yes, but its still a trick. The fact that there are two lines to type, chance of them getting slip up increases the risk and makes debugging difficult. My library approach is just a way to keep all functions in one file, which people may not like. I can see the benefit of keeping all functions in separate files (C++ vs Java approach). But I love your trick! I think there are great places to apply it and I'll be sure to remember it :D