# Run a Command Prompt command from Desktop Shortcut

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt, shortcut

Is it possible to create a desktop shortcut that, when pressed, will open command prompt and run a pre-defined command?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The solutions turned out to be very simple.

1. Open text edit
2. Write the command, save as .bat.
3. Double click the file created and the command automatically starts running in command-prompt.

[image]

Comment: I would like to add to PhilipK's answer. His approach is correct. But you need to save the .bat file to the right place. For example, i tried to create a shortcut to run "outlook /safe". I saved the .bat file to the desktop. It didn't work. It however worked after I saved the file to the location where "outlook.exe" was. This shows the location of the file matters.

Comment: If you really wanted to have it run from the desktop couldn't you add 'cd Applications'(or cd what ever directory you need to be in) to the beginning of the script? Or better yet check if location is Applications Folder and if not then change directory to the proper one. 

You make a good point though, anyone doing this should consider.

Comment: You could just put in the batch file:
`@echo off `
`cd "%HOMEDRIVE%/Your/Path/To/program.exe" `
How is this the accepted answer, though?

Comment: This was one of the first answers and still the simplest for across all windows for me (feels more like linux). I've up voted a lot of the answers too very good information.

Comment: @nashwan I interpret "shortcut" is a clickable icon on the desktop.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride I can see that :-)

Comment: See the top voted response above. This "answer", while it does work, is much more complex than needed.

Comment: I like the approach, but I don't see how this actually runs anything in the command prompt.

Comment: if copying screenshot from other answer and pasting your own, I do not think my answer need to be here

Comment: I have to add since the OP question is general. For running commands requiring administrator privileges from .bat file refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file

Answer (score 198):

## Create A Shortcut That Opens The Command Prompt & Runs A Command:

Yes! You can create a shortcut to cmd.exe with a command specified after it. Alternatively you could create a batch script, if your goal is just to have a clickable way to run commands.

**Steps:**

1. Right click on some empty space in Explorer, and in the context menu go to "New/Shortcut".
2. When prompted to enter a location put either:

"`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k your-command`" This will run the command and keep (**/k**) the command prompt open after.

or

"`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c your-command`" This will run the command and the close (**/c**) the command prompt.

**Notes:**

- Tested, and working on Windows 8 - Core X86-64 September 12 2014
- If you want to have more than one command, place an "&" symbol in between them. For example: "`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k command1 & command2`".

Comment: you can type `cmd` instead of the entire path

Comment: Addition: replace 'Example' by a bat-file. C:/workspace/startup.bat to load a bat file which prepares your command window. Hint: I always add color to the different command-shortcuts that I startup. Easy to see where you are working. Add them in the shortcut properties (right-click).

Comment: I use this method to open a command prompt then run a "setup" batch command file to setup parameters for future work.

Comment: @JoeCotton can you elaborate on this? It seems like that would be a good response to the problem that once you have created the shortcut, it is really inconvenient to edit it.

Comment: Reply to @Kukas  You want to edit a short cut?  Right click on the shortcut and choose Properties from the dropdown.

Comment: I found that if you needed to use a path in your command and that path had spaces you need to surround the path with double quotes and surrounding the whole command with brackets like this: `cmd /c ("C:/Users/My name is Bruh/Desktop/java.exe" "C:/Program Files/bruhScript")`

Answer (score 53):

Yes, make the shortcut's path

```
%comspec% /k <command>
```

where

- `%comspec%` is the environment variable for cmd.exe's full path, equivalent to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` on most (if not all) Windows installs
- `/k` keeps the window open after the command has run, this may be replaced with `/c` if you want the window to close once the command is finished running
- `<command>` is the command you wish to run

Comment: I found that if you needed to use a path in your command and that path had spaces you need to surround the path with double quotes and surrounding the whole command with brackets like this: `cmd /c ("C:/Users/My name is Bruh/Desktop/java.exe" "C:/Program Files/bruhScript")`

Answer (score 15):

1. Create new text file on desktop;
2. Enter desired commands in text file;
3. Rename extension of text file from ".txt" --> ".bat"

Answer (score 11):

Yes. One option you have is to create a batch file containing the command

> cmd -c {your command}

or

> cmd -k {your command}

The shortcut will then be to this batch file.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, k = keep and c = close and specify what happens after the command is finished.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler, Did you guess that?

Comment: I can't remember, but if you Google it you can find a command line reference for cmd online.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler, Well usually they don't tell what the shortcut stands for...

Comment: For me, it had to be `/K` not `-k`.

Comment: How to chain/pass multiple commands followed by a SINGLE "cmd" command, I tried the "&" sign to no avail. e.g. cmd hostname & whoami & dir c:\

Answer (score 6):

This is an old post but I have issues with coming across posts that have some incorrect information/syntax...

If you wanted to do this with a shorcut icon you could just create a shortcut on  your desktop for the cmd.exe application. Then append a /K {your command} to the shorcut path.

So a default shorcut target path may look like "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe", just change it to %windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k {commands}

example: %windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k powercfg -lastwake

In this case i would use /k (keep open) to display results.

Arlen was right about the /k (keep open) and /c (close)

You can open a command prompt and type "cmd /?" to see your options.

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true

A batch file is kind of overkill for a single command prompt command...

Hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 3):

I tried this, all it did was open a cmd prompt with "cmd -c (my command)" 
and didn't actually run it.  see below.

C:\windows\System32>cmd -c (powercfg /lastwake)
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\windows\System32>

***Update
I changed my .bat file to read "cmd /k (powercfg /lastwake)" and it worked. 
You can also leave out the () and it works too.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Drag and Drop method

1. From the windows search bar type in `cmd` to pull up the windows bar operation.
2. When the command line option is shown, right click it and select `Open File Location`.
3. The file explorer opens and the shortcut link is highlighted in the folder. If it is not highlighted, then select it.
4. Hold down the <kbd>Control</kbd> key and using the mouse drag the shortcut to the desktop. *If you don't see `Copy to Desktop` while dragging and before dropping, then push down and hold the <kbd>Control</kbd> key until you see the message.*
5. Drop the link on the desktop.
6. Change properties as needed.