# how to give multiple command to cmd.exe after opening it using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python.
I want below things to happen in windows after running python script:
1. cmd.exe should open
2. move to another directory(in cmd)
3. run the .exe file in that directory

I just want all these step in python script

Comment: Can you please explain once again what do you mean?

Comment: From what I understand you want to open in Python cmd.exe, change working directory and then run some other executable file.

Comment: Also related: [Run a Command Prompt command from Desktop Shortcut](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9738434)

Comment: For example, I just want to open Cmd.exe in windows using python script and just want to give multiple input to it serially like as I said above.

Comment: @Patryk Perduta yes

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module to run `cmd.exe` with some extra switches; separate multiple commands with `&`. See the duplicates I linked to for details.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters could you please provide one example