# Batch file that run jar file on cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Apologies if duplicate, I want to run a jar file from command prompt, So instead of going to the specific path can i create a batch file,
Simply double click on batch file will do my task,
I found something at [1]: [Run a Command Prompt command from Desktop Shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738434/run-a-command-prompt-command-from-desktop-shortcut) but it do not work in my case, I want to run `java -jar squirrel-sql.jar`

I would like to make a batch file that:

1)Opens cmd.exe

2)Within that Command Prompt runs `java -jar squirrel-sql.jar` which is present on desktop

3)Leaves the window open so that I can run additional commands if I wish to
How can I do this?

Comment: try `start cmd /k java -jar squirrel-sql.jar`

Comment: @nouseforname : It works Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Save the following as **squirrel.bat**:

```
java -jar squirrel-sql.jar

REM /P causes SET to prompt and wait for Enter.
REM The underscore is used to ensure that "sure" is not already
REM an environment variable.
set /p _sure="Do you want to exit? [press Enter]"

REM /I causes a case-insensitive comparison
if /I NOT "_sure"=="y" (
  REM /B exits the batch script but not the CMD window
  exit /b
) else (
  REM Any other modifications
)
```

Comment: use this code and save a .bat file extention and duble click on that bat file it will run fine

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Even though your answer might be valid, it will not be informative to any future user having the same problem. Could you please elaborate in your answer on what your code does and how it fixes the problem in the question?

Comment: This is used to run jar and perform different operation without closing cmd.as per user wish if they wish exit from jar but not cmd.