# Run multiple commands without creating batch file using command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

My problem is this - In Win 10 user account, I created a batch file which opens a bunch of files. When I logout and log back in, the batch file just disappears!

So I started looking at options. One good option is this: create a shortcut which can run multiple commands. ([Run a Command Prompt command from Desktop Shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738434/run-a-command-prompt-command-from-desktop-shortcut)). This doesn't work as is as my command line is too long. Also all the commands are hidden in the shortcut.

What I ideally need is to still create a shortcut as above which calls a command prompt but the command prompt should execute commands from a text file.

So to sum it up, I need this setup to work:
- create a text file which will have multiple commands separated by &
- create a shortcut which calls a command prompt and this command prompt execute commands from the text file above

Thanks!

Comment: Hi - I haven't received any responses/comments. Is the question clear? Anything I should add to clarify?

Comment: a batch file doesn't tend to disappear. Can you please explain more?

Comment: Batch file disappearring is the original problem.  Let me explain - I was originally logging in as admin and was executing the .bat file. This setup was working fine. But then I decided (wisely, i think from the security perspective) to create a new admin account & convert my current admin account to user account. Now when I login to user account, the .bat file just disappears! I can reproduce this error by creating a .bat file again, shutdown and restart the computer and its gone again.  It would help to get an idea as to why that is happening but my current question is different from that.