# How to make a shortcut for javafx application

Tags: java, javafx, jar, executable-jar, double-click

I thought I could find an answer for this question because as i think it is popular problem.But unfortunately I did not find the answer

I have an application written with **Java** and **JavaFX**
and i built it using eclipse and it worked perfectly there

but when I export the project as a **.jar**(executable jar file) file so it runs when it is double clicked it doesn't work

I tried a lot of things and I could approve that their is **no exceptions or errors** in the jar file by running it from the **cmd** and it worked perfectly but i still need it to be run by clicking a shortcut like an **.[exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW8q3.png)** file or any kind of such a thing and it should run when it is sent to another computer

this image proves it is working in the cmd

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkZ6W.png)

Comment: Make sure you have a main-class attribute in your JAR manifest. If you haven't already, you also need to associate JAR files with Java. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64

Comment: I found a _**solution**_ that worked perfectly [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9740064)