# How to add batch file in windows environment variable

Tags: windows, environment-variables, openvino

I am following the [installation guide](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html) for openvino on Windows. After a successful installation, we need to run `setupvars.bat` file in order to initialize the openvino environment. We can also [add it permanently in environment variable](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html#set-the-environment-variables) so that it is initialized automatically. But the instructions are not given on how to add it.

I wanted to know if its possible to add the `setupvars.bat` so the it runs automatically. Also I need to run the visual studio from the same environment.

I always do this step manually which takes a lot time. I first open a `cmd`, navigate to the desired folder and then run `setupvars.bat`. After that from the same `cmd`, I navigate to the visual studio installed directory and then start the visual studio from the `cmd` so that visual studio is launched under same openvino environment. Is is possible to automate all this task. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**: You can set the environment variables for the visual studio as mentioned here - [How do I set specific environment variables when debugging in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100543/how-do-i-set-specific-environment-variables-when-debugging-in-visual-studio)

**Solution 2**: Write one more batch file which will 1st call setupvars.bat & then open the visual studio. Then you can run the new bat file.

**Solution 3:** You can create a cmd shortcut like this - [Run a Command Prompt command from Desktop Shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738434/run-a-command-prompt-command-from-desktop-shortcut) 
In this, you can 1st call setupvars.bat and then cmd to open Visual Studio. Once you click the new shortcut both the things should happen automatically. You can even add this step along with the installer.