# Run a batch file with administrator account from a network drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, administrator, network-drive

The script given in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967) works perfectly when running from a local drive accessible to both the normal user and the administrator.

However, when run from a network drive (which is a very real possibility in University environments) it runs into file not found issues.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went for the simplest workaround: The batch file now copies all files it requires to the user's temp folder (which is local & accessible to admins) before running the "as admin" part.

Bit of a hassle, large & ugly batch file, but it works

Answer (score 2):

This is a new "feature" of UAC in windows,  try this regkey:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v EnableLinkedConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
```

For more information on this regkey, check out this technet article: [LINK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Hold on, do you mean that's a bug in windows 8? Or is this a line of code that'll only work in windows 8?

Comment: MS did this on purpose, check out the link that I put in the post

Comment: great. work win 10