# Antivirus programs kick on my exe file

Tags: batch-file, exe, antivirus, virus

I have converted a batch file to exe. My problem is that all virusprograms think this is a "trojan attack" and delete the file. Is there a quickfix for this? Reason for not using the original batch file is that Users of the file forgets the "run as administrator" and with the exe I can force it.

```
@echo off
%~d0\bat\menu.bat
```

Comment: The AV programs are correct.  Any exe that elevates privilege for itself is potentially a Trojan.  And any "quick fix" would represent an unacceptable security flaw.

Comment: cant you create a shortcut with 'run as administrator' thick?

Comment: See also this: http://superuser.com/questions/604927/how-do-i-configure-my-application-to-run-as-administrator-automatically

Comment: See also this: https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/scripts/batchgotadmin And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file

Comment: I can not run from shortcut because drive will be random. '%~d0\' does not work in a shortcut. the bacth is placed in a usbdrive

Answer (score 0):

You could create a shortcut with admin prompt and run it. This is using the `shortcut.exe` file from [**this site**](http://ss64.com/nt/shortcut.html). I haven't actually tested this code.

```
shortcut -f -t runas /user:%computername%\administrator %cd%\batchfile.bat -n %cd%\startfile
start %cd%\startfile.lnk
```