# Running command prompt in Administrator mode once it is open in user mode?

Tags: windows-8.1, command-prompt, administrator

I have writen my code but i have to make a file copy to startup located in C: for which i need to have administrator request. So, can you help me to get administrator access using the non-administrator command line. Is there any command to get there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to request Administrator access inside a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, the administrator account is **AAA** and you want to run **BBB.exe** of **`C:\programs`**, you should do these following steps:

1. Press **Win key & R**
2. Input `CMD` in open box and click `OK`
3. Input: `runas /profile /user:AAA “C:\programs\BBB.exe`  and press `Enter`
4. Input the **password of administrator** `AAA`
5. Press `Enter`.

Hope it works.

Comment: @krishnachalise did you check this??

Comment: You could perhaps change the `“C:\programs\BBB.exe` to `cmd` so that he will have a command line with administrative access.