# Give Admin privileges to exe application

Tags: batch-file, admin, command-prompt

I'm starting an exe application through a .bat file, I want to start it granting admin privileges to it. How can I do it in a .bat file.

Comment: Could you please provide the things you already tried using answers from search engines to your topic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to request Administrator access inside a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

Two basic options:

1. Run the script as admin
2. Use the 'runas' command e.g.
   runas /user:administrator blah.exe
   Runas will then prompt for the admin password.