# Is there any way I can run a batch file with administrator privileges ( without right clicking and selecting "Run as admin")

Tags: batch-file, cmd, admin

I'm actually looking for a way to run the batch file as admin by using a code. If that is not possible is there any way to run an .exe file as admin by default?

Comment: No. If there was, it would be a pretty significant security hole. Even when logged in as an administrator, things that require admin privileges don't execute without permission being explicitly granted; this includes batch files, where you have to use *Run as administrator* when opening the command prompt to execute them or run them from Explorer.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, now i realize that. Thanks buddy.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/852877

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to request Administrator access inside a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file)

Comment: @JosefZ, please flag this as duplicate. I already did.

Comment: @manjesh23 my comment was generated automatically from _casting_, see [Cast Close And Reopen Votes](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege. No need to flag; _flagging_ would be superabundant action…