# how to add my registry key to a batch file so that it runs automatically

Tags: windows

i have the following registry key:

```
HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/SideBySide/PreferExternalManifest
```

its a DWORD 32, Decimal and the value is 1

how can i add this using REG ADD?

Comment: so i got this to work sort of:  REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide" /v PreferExternalManifest /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f, but the problem is that it is a hex format and not decimal. how can i do that?

Comment: 1 is 1 in hex or decimal. It is the exact same value.

Comment: By the way, you will need administration rights to run this in a batch file. If you wish to automatically prompt for admin rights, take a look at this [RequestAdminElevation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file/30590134#30590134) script