# .bat file with some commands as admin and other as normal user

Tags: batch-file, cmd, admin

I'm struggling with defining a single bat file which consists of some commands that need to run in admin mode and other in regular mode. 
(part 1:admin, part 2: normal, part 3: admin)

The closest solution I could think of is to define one files that call 3 different files. (The first part of file Init1, Init3 define admin mode which is copied from  https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/scripts/batchgotadmin)

Unfortunately it seems that the files are not executed one by one and I don't reach Init3.

I Defined the following files:

**MainInit.bat**

```
call Init1

call Init2

call Init3
```

---

**Init1.bat:**

// code from [How to request Administrator access inside a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file/10052222#10052222)

```
echo "1"

exit
```

---

**Init2.bat:**

```
echo "2"

exit
```

---

**Init3.bat:**

// code from [How to request Administrator access inside a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file/10052222#10052222)

```
echo "3"

exit
```

Comment: you can achieve that with `RUNAS` or `SCHTASKS` commands but it will mean to store somewhere the admin password. The pass/script can be obfuscated but still will easy to get it.

Comment: Why can't you just run all 3 commands as an admin?