# how open .conf file with admin rights, edit and save using bat

Tags: batch-file

This is the content of the conf file

use chroot = false

strict modes = false

hosts allow = *

log file = rsyncd.log

i need to add this two lines in the begin

uid=0

gid=0

and this other lines in the end

[data]

path = /cygdrive/d/My documents

read only = false

transfer logging = yes

[mail]

path = /cygdrive/d/mail

read only = false

transfer logging = yes

with the bat completed i will going to deploy it by policy on my network.

i´m really new in this, but i appreciate your help. Apologies for my english.

I tried with this code:

```
@echo off
Color 9A & Mode con cols=83 lines=5
Title %~n0 Adding lines to rsyncd.conf
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
REM  --> Check for permissions
Reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19\Environment" >nul 2>&1
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
Echo.
ECHO                      **************************************
ECHO                       Running Admin shell... Please wait...
ECHO                      **************************************
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B
:gotAdmin
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set "hostspath=C:\Program Files (x86)\ICW\rsyncd.conf"
FIND /C /I "uid=0" "%hostspath%" >nul
FIND /C /I "gid=0" "%hostspath%" >nul
FIND /C /I "[data]" "%hostspath%" >nul
FIND /C /I "path = /cygdrive/d/My documents" "%hostspath%" >nul
FIND /C /I "read only = false" "%hostspath%" >nul
FIND /C /I "transfer logging = yes" "%hostspath%" >nul
FIND /C /I "[mail]" "%hostspath%" >nul
FIND /C /I "path = /cygdrive/d/mail" "%hostspath%" >nul
FIND /C /I "read only = false" "%hostspath%" >nul
FIND /C /I "transfer logging = yes" "%hostspath%" >nul
) 
Attrib +R "%hostspath%"
```

Comment: It's fine to be new, but this is a programmer Q&A site, so you will need to demonstrate some effort at solving the problem rather than just asking others to do it for you.

Comment: i forget mention this is the route to the file C:\Program Files (x86)\ICW\rsyncd.conf

Comment: i tried with this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file/30590134#30590134) to get admin rights. Just copy the script to the end of a batch file with this script in the beginning:

```
@echo off

:: Run this script with elevation
call :RequestAdminElevation "%~dpfs0" %* || goto:eof

set "hostspath=C:\Program Files (x86)\ICW\rsyncd.conf"
set "new_hostspath=C:\Program Files (x86)\ICW\rsyncd.temp"

:: Add the first lines to the new file
echo uid=0> %new_hostspath%
echo gid=0>> %new_hostspath%

:: copy your original .conf file to the new one
type %hostspath% >> %new_hostspath%

:: add the last lines to the new file
echo [data] >> %new_hostspath%
echo path = /cygdrive/d/My documents >> %new_hostspath%
echo read only = false >> %new_hostspath%
echo transfer logging = yes >> %new_hostspath%
echo [mail] >> %new_hostspath%
echo path = /cygdrive/d/mail >> %new_hostspath%
echo read only = false >> %new_hostspath%
echo transfer logging = yes >> %new_hostspath%

:: copy new file over the old file
type %new_hostspath% > %hostspath

pause &goto:eof

[here you paste the RequestAdminElevation function code]
```

Comment: Thank you cyberponk, now I have a light in my road to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All of the `find` commands are doing nothing - they simply check that the string is within the file and set `errorlevel` to 0 if found, non-0 if not - but having done the `find` you are doing nothing with the result.

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set "hostspath=C:\Program Files (x86)\ICW\rsyncd.conf"
FIND /C /I "uid=0" "%hostspath%" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto :eof
Attrib -R "%hostspath%"
(for %%a in ("gid=0" "uid=0") do echo %%~a)>tempfile.txt
type "%hostspath%" >>tempfile.txt
(for %%a in ("[data]"
 "uid=0"
"path = /cygdrive/d/My documents"
"read only = false"
"transfer logging = yes" 
"[mail]" 
"path = /cygdrive/d/mail"
"read only = false"
"transfer logging = yes"
 ) do echo %%~a
)>>tempfile.txt
move /y tempfile.txt "%hostspath%" 
Attrib +R "%hostspath%"
```

First, check whether `uid=0` is in the file. If it is, assume the job has already been done and exit.

Remove the readonly flag from the `.conf` file

The `for` command will assign the "values in quotes" to `%%a` in turn, then `echo` each value (the `~` removes the enclosing quotes). The `(` and `)` enclosing the `for` command allow the output to be redirected to a file hich I named `tempfile.txt`.

Then type the contents of the existing `.conf` file to the tempfile

Then output the remaining lines, but this time the redirector is `>>` to append to `tempfile.txt`

Then move `tempfile.txt` over the `.conf` file and mark it readonly.