# How to launch an app with elevated privileges on Vista+ using Java / JNA to trigger UAC

Tags: java, uac, jna

I'd like to programmatically launch an application (a second JVM) from a Java app using JNA.

Please note that I can't :

- add a Windows manifest to the JVM (minimal impact on the client)
- use right click "runas administrator" (clicking "Allow" in the UAC dialog will be complicated enough)

I've seen other Questions with answers that states "use an exe" like [Java: run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator/1385901#1385901) but I was wondering if anybody tried this using JNA

Answer (score 1):

To start an application with elevated privileges, you have to use `ShellExecute` and pass `"runas"` as the value of `lpOperation` parameter. This method does not require you to modify the JVM to add manifest to it. This behaves as if user right-clicked the application and selected *Run as administrator* command.

Note: on Windows XP, you should not use `"runas"` because it prompts for user credentials.