# jar file with admin privilege

Tags: jar

Is there a way in java to execute the jar file with administration privilege, when double click on jar file open with admin privilege ?

i know this way: go to C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin and right click on javaw.exe file
choose compatibility and click on run this program as an administrator.

but this way isn't an appropriate for normal application users >>>

Thanks.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator

Answer (score 1):

You could call the JRE from an executable and add an administrator manifest.

[Bat To Exe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/) works nice for such workarounds.

It will allow you to write a batch file and convert it into an self-extracting executable that contains your .jar file.