# How to obtain administrator rights in java web start application, need to writting in system directories

Tags: java, windows, security, permissions, java-web-start

I'm going to develop a java web start application, which need to access protected system directory and install a program there.

I know, how to exit sandbox, my application is signed and have access to filesystem. The problem is, that it sill can't access directories like C:/windows/system32.

I found solutions for standalone java applications:
[Java: run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator)

How to do this in java web start?

Thanks in advance for answer!

Comment: I would be really worried if a web-start application could have administration rights and make changes in the windows folder.  I'm not sure if it is possible but I hope it is not.

Comment: I'm just going to automatically install a program needed by my application. It should ask about privileges, and then user accept or reject it. I think it should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can probably try to use the following trick:

1. Precompile a jar file with the Manifest pointing to the main
   class, that carries out all of the required filesystem routines
2. Put this jar somewhere into the resources folder of your Web-Start
   application and then copy it into the user's Temp folder upon
   Web-Start execution
3. Provision required files from the elevation
   [PowerToys](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.06.elevation.aspx)
   in the similar manner
4. Call " %PATH_TO_USER_TEMP%/elevate"
   command together with "java -jar %PATH_TO_USER_TEMP%/yourJar.jar"
   (please refer to the article above or additional documentation on
   the Elevation PowerToys to find out the details)
5. If everything
   works out, user shall be presented with a request to grant the
   executed java process required Admin privileges.