# How to run setup.exe file using java

Tags: java, security, permissions, runtime.exec

I am developing an java application from which I have to run xyz_setup.exe installer. I tried the following code

```
String command = "C:\\xyz_setup.exe"; 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);`
```

But it was throwing the following error

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\NewtonApples\Downloads\idman614.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:345)
    at upendra.OpenExternalApplication.main(OpenExternalApplication.java:19)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:189)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:133)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
    ... 4 more
```

Can any one suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator

Comment: @madhairsilence as Java developer, you don't always have control over executable (such as `java.exe`) which runs your code - often doing manifest etc is not an option. This is legitimate problem, and one possible solution to it is to run the program via `cmd`, which knows how to request privilege elevation. He's not asking to elevate current process - he only wants to run elevated setup, which is a different problem, so this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java (or likely any other process which uses `CreateProcess` system call directly) is not good with executables requiring access elevation.
You can get around that by executing your program via shell:

```
  String command = "C:\\setup.exe";
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c "+command);
```

Comment: This is running perfectly but when the executable file is in following location it was showing an error. **Path: E:\\New folder\\Setup.exe**

Comment: That's because you have space in folder name - enclose it in double quotes: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"" + command + "\"");`

Comment: Thank you. It's working fine. Is it possible to trace the progress of the installation. That means after completing the Setup.exe installation I have to display 'Successfully Completed Installation' message through java. Regard's

Comment: But of course. [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) returns object of type [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). On that, you can do `exitValue()` to obtain exit code of your setup program. `getOutputStream()` and `getErrorStream()` will give you its standard output and standard error streams. To get all of that, you have to do `Process.waitFor()` first, of course, to wait for it to finish. Non-zero exit code most likely indicates failure, but check your specific setup.