# Java execute .exe with user previlege

Tags: java, windows, permissions, cmd

I've written a program in c# to change file and folder atributes in windows.
I run this program from java, starting the program from windows all
works great, in java just files can be changed when i try to change a folder
it throws:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: fileattr.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5203a06f
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.18052
  Problem Signature 06: 5173c144
  Problem Signature 07: 43cf
  Problem Signature 08: 13c
  Problem Signature 09: System.UnauthorizedAccess
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
```

I've set the processbuilder directory to user.home thinking that problem could come
because of that but doesn't work.
My code:

```
try {

                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("fileattr", "+t",                   "\"".concat(path).concat("\""));
                pb.environment().put("fileattr", pathToApp);
                pb.directory(new File(System.getenv("WINDIR") + "\\system32"));
                Process p = pb.start();
                p.waitFor();
                p.destroy();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried starting the JVM as Administrator?

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance but how can i do that? Adding a manifest to should work?
Process is launched in the user context or in jvm context?

Answer (score 0):

I think according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator) thread, you have two possibilities :

- You can [add a manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) for your fileattr.exe
- You can use [elevate.exe](http://int3.de/download/Elevate.zip), run the binary using : `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("elevate", "fileattr");`

I hope i answered you question.

Answer (score 0):

First possibility didn't solve, i've build the filleattr with the manifest file for two options of UAC level:

```
highestAvailable|requireAdministrator
```

Here's the manifest:

```
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
```

Second have an issue, i include both .exe files in java jar, when program starts extract
.exe files and try to execute them, the problem, the extraction process is modifying something in executable, when i try to run the original file all works perfect, otherwise it throw's:

`This version of C:\Users\Luis\SyncData\Elevate.exe is not compatible with th
e version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to
 see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and
 then contact the software publisher.`

Maybe @Templar sugestion should work, i just need to grant JVM user permission's that is enough to change folder atributtes, i'll try that.

Important to refer that from 30 and 30 seconds a thread call this method a large number of times, so the permission need's to be permanent otherwise it will not work properly.