# exe from java can not be run correctly

Tags: java, cmd

I'm trying to run `.exe` file from my java file.
If I run this `.exe` console program manualy by double clicking, it does everything it should.
If I run it from my .jar file by using this:

```
ProcessBuilder x = new ProcessBuilder("\"" + myLocation + "\\1.exe\"");
                    x.start();
```

It runs a cmd window with a title like C:\user\Josh\1.exe, but it does nothing. It does not do anything what this .exe file should do.

Everything what is in this console window is:

> Microsoft Windows  Copyright.. etc..

just typical thing what appears when you run simply cmd.exe

I am really hopeless, please help. I tried to do it using this:

```
Process xx = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(aa);
```

where aa is location of file, but it does the same thing.

Comment: What happens when you try to run 1.exe directly from a cmd console?

Comment: I just found out, that there is also problem with creating new process, because 1:exe need administration privilegies. How can I run it?(ofcourse users have to confirm this program in UAV)

Comment: @acbabis: it runs correctly from console, also with using doubleclick

Comment: Try right-clicking the JAR and running as administrator.

Comment: JAR can not be runned as administrator by right-clicking. only JVM :/

Comment: OK, I know this might not be very helpful, but you *can* right-click to run cmd as an admin, then use the cmd to run java. \*Inception music\*

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but it has to be runned from java file :(

Comment: The general case of running an exe from Java is pretty complex.  I had some code to do it once and it ran a hundred lines or so.

Comment: It looks like this might be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator . Possible Duplicate.

Comment: I already have manifest for my exe. Still can not run it with ProcessBuilder... maybe because of this manifest. So I had to use runtime.exec ()

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program) might help. Some processes won't progress correctly if their output doesn't get flushed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using Runtime.exec().... unfortunately :(

String myCommandString = "cmd /C start " + myLoc + "\1.exe";
Process xx = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myCommandString);

It also runs 1.exe with admin privilegies... I mean it ask for them.