# File exists but java file.exists() but return false

Tags: java, file, exists

As the title says, I'm checking if a file exists or not with java.
The file is stored in

> C:\Windows\System32.

If I run the project with `Netbeans`, no problem. It returns true.

But if I run the `.jar`, it returns false.
I'm admin of the computer, but I don't know which privilege I have when I run the `.jar`.

Do you have any idea

Comment: And the code is?

Comment: 'code' File dest = new File("C:\\Windows\\System32\\" + myFile);

Comment: And I check the value of dest.exist().

Comment: You should [edit that code into the question body](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28810714/edit) ideally - code in comments tends to get missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run cmd.exe as an admin and then run your .jar from this cmd. Being an admin does not mean you are starting your apps with admin privilege.

Comment: That's it!
If I don't run the cmd.exe as admin, it still returns false.
But if I run it as an admin, it returns true!

So how can I run my jar file with admin privilege?

Comment: That has been already answered before; see here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html), you should check also `Files.notExists` - if it returns `false`, too, your program failed to verify the existence of the file.

Comment: That should be `Files.notExists` ... `File` and `Files` are different classes.

Comment: If it is not a typo, it is an error. because `File.notExists` (sic) does not exist.  (Sick :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to run CMD as an administrator and then run your .jar file, like you didn't post the code we can't get a good idea about your issue.