# CMD in administrator through Java

Tags: java, cmd, adhoc

I want to use netsh command through java . Netsh works only in cmd administartor mode . How to use netsh in cmd in administartor mode through java and make adhoc network via command mode.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried elevate.exe?
Go through this blog [Johannes Passing's Blog](http://jpassing.com/2007/12/08/launch-elevated-processes-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: Alternatively go through this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator