# System cannot define the specific file in java

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I am trying to read a file from the hard disk in java. However when I am trying to: `BufferedReader   inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("weather.txt"));` and I'm receiving the following message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\weather.txt (System cannot define the specific file)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)
>       at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:58)

I tried to change the location of the file many times. However I got the same error. The location of the file is `C:\weather.txt`. What I am missing here?

**EDIT:** Based on the proposed answer I tried to do the following:

```
File targetFile = new File("C:\\", "weather.txt");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(targetFile);//BufferedReader datafile = readDataFile("C://weather.txt");
BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

It seems that I cant use at all bufferedReader. What is happening here?

Comment: Try:  `FileReader("C:\\weather.txt")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error as stated by you is completely depends on `java.io.FileNotFoundException` exception. This exception occurred due to try to open a file which not exist in the given path. As you are trying to get a `BufferedReader` out of the file name, you better need to check of the file exist or not, before opening it.

**Possible remedy**

```
public static BufferedReader getFileBufferedReader(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    File file = new File(fileName);
    if (!file.exists()) {  
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.close();
    }
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    return new BufferedReader(fr);
}
```

**Idea**

First confirm if the given `fileName` exist or not by using `file.exists()` method and then if file not exist, create one file with the name as given in `fileName`. As soon as there is an existing file your method will work and you can return a `BufferedReader` out of `fileName`.

Comment: Yup I got it. file.exists doesnot seem to find the file. However the file is the provided location? Is there a way that I got issues due to admin rights?

Comment: To get **admin** rights, check this out, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator]

Comment: I found it, it seems that the file was stored weather.txt.txt. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
  File targetFile = new File(targetPath, filename);
```

Or you can create a folder `C:\\folder\\weather.txt` somewhere else.

Comment: However my code is inside a function which returns a bufferedReader how can I return instead a file? What is the relationship between bufferedReader and File?

Comment: `new BufferedReader(new FileReader(targetFile));` will do the work