# Why can a .exe file not be launched from this piece of code?

Tags: java, exe

I'm working on a packet analyser program and have encountered some issues:

1. I want to open an exe file that would capture packets and write to another file.
2. I want to open it in elevated mode.

I have written somewhat :

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Options extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private void recActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            try {
                File myFile = new File(
                        "C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\response\\Server_Analyser\\src\\server_analyser\\serverdump\\reader.exe");
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry cannot find desired file !");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using Desktop, create a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), and call its inheritIO() method before starting the process.  That will tell you what’s going wrong—which I suspect will turn out to be a message about insufficient permissions.

Comment: "Opening an exe file" doesn't mean what you think it means. Your code opens it, but what you want to do is running it.

Answer (score 1):

The `Desktop.getDesktop().open(FILE)` command opens the file with the associated program only. This would work for example with a `.txt` file that is associated with notepad. As a `.exe` is not associated, as it is a program on its own, it won't work.

To run a `.exe` from your java code you can use this command

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\response\\Server_Analyser\\src\\server_analyser\\serverdump\\reader.exe").start();
```

This way you also can control the executed program over your java application and e.g. shut it down again.

Comment: I got that.Help me out on how to open an exe in elevated mode.

Comment: This is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator
I don't know your program. It might be easier if you start your program already elevated to skip this step. But I don't know if the use of your program allows that.