# how to get 'Run as administrator' in jar applications

Tags: java

I have a desktop java application that uses Swing as a GUI library. There is an installer that I have to install inside this application, but **it must have administrative privileges**.

I am using

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pathToTheExeInstaller);
```

to install the program. But it has this error when running it without administrator privilege:

[image: error]

Is there a way to get *Run as administrator* in the context menu (the right click menu) in the generated jar file when clean and build is used in NetBeans:

[image]

Comment: Try running cmd as administrator and starting your jar from there maybe.

Comment: This will work, but as a client I don't want him to run cmd as administrator, I want him to simply just click a button.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator

Comment: I tried to do it, getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell.exe Start-Process 'pathToTheExeInstaller' -verb RunAs");
```

This will give a prompt to the user asking permissions to get elevated access for your installer.

<sub>Extracted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40027004/2408342)</sub>

---

Example

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell.exe Start-Process 'notepad.exe' -verb RunAs");
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, it gives an error with the arguments, the path contains spaces, so I put "", still gives an error.

Comment: I did, but the problem is that the path has `~1` in it, it what `createTempDirectory` returns.

Comment: I'm getting this error:
`Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process C:\Users\TAREQK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\NSIS Installer7238 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand`

Comment: @Tarek I've edited the answer, check it now. Use `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: yeah sorry I forgot.

Comment: I assume this only work on windows, is there a solution that works on any platform ?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the "command prompt" and choose "run as administrator", then you can

```
java -jar myprogram.jar
```

Comment: Read the comments. OP doesn't want to do this.