# Execute external program with administrator rights

Tags: java, runtime.exec, administrator, admin-rights

I am trying to open an extenal program that requires me to open this program as administrator.

I am using these two lines to open external program, but the program is executed without administrator privileges.

How i can execute it with the correct rights?

```
Runtime run  = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
Process proc = run.exec(locationOfProgram);
```

Comment: What is *manager*, are you perhaps talking about **administrator**?

Comment: @Zabuzard Yes..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator)

Comment: @Zabuzard Have you read the 3rd or 4th answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385901/5043481