# Start Java Runtime Process with Administrator rights on Vista

Tags: java, windows-vista, process, runtime, privileges

i want to execute a setup.exe installer which installes a software on vista with java 1.6.

The user is not an administrator. When i try to start the process i get the error message:

```
CreateProcess error=740
```

which indicates, that the user has not enough rights for starting the process.

Can i  submit a flag or an option to indicate, the the process should execute with administrator rights? Vista itself does have this functionality inside the menu toolbar. Can i use this function in Java.

I call the following code

```
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process;
        try {
            String fileToExecute = new File(mFolder, mSetupFiles[0]).getCanonicalPath();

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Execute runtime process");
            }
            process = rt.exec(fileToExecute, null, mFolder);

            process.getErrorStream().close();
            process.getInputStream().close();
            process.getOutputStream().close();

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Wait until process is finished");
            }
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new StartException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new StartException(e);
        }
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong about this, but it seems you're asking for a way to allow a 'setup.exe' installer to override the OS and GIVE ITSELF ADMINISTRATIVE PRIVILEGES! Of course, I could have misunderstood, but this sounds risky.

Comment: What i want is, that Vista is asking for the admin username/password when it is required before/during opening a file with permissions.

Comment: Yes, I see, that would be better. Vista asks for the username & password and then execution continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 days of testing i found the following solution.

The error comes up when the Vista UAC functionality is activated. UAC shows a question dialog everytime, when a process needs administrator rights.

Showing this dialog causes the issue.

Instead of using the old

```
process = rt.exec(fileToExecute, null, mFolder);
```

command, i am using now the new 1.5 [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) command

**EDIT:**

To avoid the problem you have to open a command window which requests the permission. And than you have to call the external process.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/C", fileToExecute });
```

Also described here [Execute an external Program](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html)

Answer (score 3):

(I have not tried this), but it seems that you can do this using the "elevate" program from [here](http://www.gilham.org/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=aab85845-88d2-4091-8088-a6bbce0a4304&ID=265)

also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076794/uac-and-java) for UAC overview