# Java: execute command in a new cmd.exe as administrator

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, exec

I want to execute a command from a Java-application using

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec(command);
```

but the command need Admin-privileges. If I use

```
runas /user:Administrator "cmdName parameters"
```

nothing happens because I need to give user und pw as parameter to the command.
But I need to run a command to the cmd, so that a new cmd.exe starts as administrator and asks if I want to run cmd.exe as admin. After agree the command should be run in the admin-cmd. So like this:

```
String command = "popupNewCmdAsAdminAndRun "batWhichNeedsAdmin.bat" "
Runtime.getRuntime.exec(command);
```

Has anyone an Idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer help?

[Start Java Runtime Process with Administrator rights on Vista](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420901/start-java-runtime-process-with-administrator-rights-on-vista)

Comment: Seems not to work for me. A new admin-cmd won't pop up :/

Answer (score 1):

you should do the following

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "command";
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit(60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Start Command Prompt (CMD) from java as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832736/start-command-prompt-cmd-from-java-as-administrator) and [Run command prompt as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596599/run-command-prompt-as-administrator) - or the silly way, try to pipe it:

```
pw | command
```

Comment: ? runas is no option for me I said, I don't want to get a pw in my java-application. The second link is more interesting, but I tried it out a few days ago, without success. I got the error "the file is not a program associated to perform this action", if I try to run "cmd /c Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState"

Answer (score 0):

Research building projects and the executable jar file. Usually when you build a project, it gives you a commandline that can be used to execute the jar file in folder dist located in the projects folder. You can copy and paste the command line in cmd. But you could also use a bat file, or convert the executable jar file into an exe with the jar2exe converter. Not completely sure of the name because i am not posting on my computer.

Comment: The code below is also valid, all depends on how you need to apply it.