# How to Run(launch) elevated command prompt programmatically in Vista

Tags: mfc, windows-vista

I'm trying to install some files from a batch file (through code).
However the command should only run as "elevated command" in Vista and Windows 7
Is there any way this can be done programitically?

I'm launching the batch file by calling "CreateProcess" in VC++/MFC code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ShellExecute(NULL, L"runas", ...);
```

For whatever reason the "runas" verb isn't [documented in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) but...