# 740: The requested operation requires elevation in java

Tags: java, windows-7

I tried this java code, in this code i move a file from from one directory to another one, 
then execute the file. I am using Windows 7 OS.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.omg.CORBA.Environment;

public class JFileChooserTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filelocation="C:\\Users\\FSSD\\Desktop\\OutPut\\Target\\setup.exe";
        File trgDir = new File(filelocation);
        System.err
                .println("file location>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
                        + filelocation);
        File desDir = new File(
                "C:\\Users\\FSSD\\IndigoWorkSpace\\Swing\\test");

        try {
            FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(trgDir, desDir);
            // FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, trgDir);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {

            Process p=rt.exec("runas /user:FSSD test/setup.exe");   
            //Process p= rt.exec("test/setup.exe");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
}
```

While i execute this i got **"740: The requested operation requires elevation "** error , if any possibilities to resolve it.

Comment: `setup.exe` was installed (or has been configured) to **Run as Administrator** ([link](http://windows-exe-errors.com/windows-error-740-the-requested-operation-requires-elevation/))

Comment: I can't understand what your trying to say

Comment: Follow the link I just provided. There's an explanation for the 740 error.

Comment: i turn OFF my UAC but the setup.exe won't work

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you can't do it in-process. You need to launch a new process that is elevated at the command line. (see the elevate command).

Please see this question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662574/how-do-i-elevate-my-uac-permissions-from-java) - they address your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Service host local system network restricted 10

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > ControlSet001**

registry value named Start in the right hand panel and double click on it.

[Link](http://www.techealthexperts.com/service-host-local-system-network-restricted-10)