# Java give admin rights in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm writing an application that should be able to save a text file to any location. When I'm running the code in eclipse I get the following Exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\myFile.txt (Zugriff verweigert)

*"Zugriff verwiegert"* is german for *permission denied*.

I can write to **C:\Users\MyUser\Documents** though.

I did some research and found out that the application needs administrator rights.
If that is true, how can I run it as administrator in eclipse?

My code to write the file:

```
try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\myFile.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.print(script.toString());
        writer.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edit:
Stackoverflow associates my question with the following one:
[How do I elevate my UAC permissions from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662574/how-do-i-elevate-my-uac-permissions-from-java)
But I want to know if it is possible in eclipse! ;D

Comment: It looks like you're asking about executing your code at a higher rights level. Have you tried running Eclipse as an administrator?

Comment: Running it as administrator worked. Don't know why I didn't come up with this by myself :D. Thank you

Comment: I'm very glad that stackoverflow doesn't delete "duplicate" questions with the way people mark them. The question that this is apparently a duplicate of says "no, you can't" and gives some workarounds (to a different, but vaguely related problem), while this question has a clean, concise "*Run Eclipse as an admin*" as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run Eclipse as Administrator, and you will be able to write anywhere on the file system

Comment: Didn't work for me :(