# How to move file from d: drive to C: drive using java

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to moves files from `D drive` to `C drive` using `Java code` (**`access denied is the error`**) but if transfered from d drive to e drive same code works

I tried following code.

```
public static void transferFile(String name) {
        try {
            File a = new File("D:\\" + name);
            System.out.println(path);
            File b = new File("C:\\" + name);
            input = new FileInputStream(a);
            output = new FileOutputStream(b);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                output.write(buf, 0, length);
            }
            input.close();
            output.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whatever user you're running the code as doesn't have permission to write to the root of the C drive.

Comment: Do you have access to **C** drive?Are you the administrator?

Comment: Have you tried running your Java program as admin (in Windows) or as root (in Linux)?  I don't think this is a code problem.

Comment: in windows 7 if we move any file manually then also it need adminstrator permission to paste the file in C: drive so i need to know how to move files using java

Comment: Blame Window's UAC: no writing to C: without giving your process administrative rights. since java can't elevate the process on the fly  the only way is to run your java-VM "as Administrator".

Comment: as piet mentioned it will be the UAC thing try disabling the uac and try

Comment: Some steps to flow to avoid these error 1.RUn your IDE(Net beans or Eclipse) as administrator 2.Right the folder and click the properties option,then uncheck read only  box

Comment: You might have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662574/how-do-i-elevate-my-uac-permissions-from-java