# Elevating a ProcessBuilder process via UAC?

Tags: java, processbuilder, elevation

I'm trying to run an external executable, but apparently it needs elevation.  The code is this, modified from an example of using ProcessBuilder (hence the array with one argument) :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File demo = new File("C:\\xyzwsdemo");
        if(!demo.exists()) demo.mkdirs();
        String[] command = {"C:\\fakepath\\bsdiff4.3-win32\\bspatch.exe"};
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( command );
        Process process = pb.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:\n", Arrays.toString(command));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        try {
            int exitValue = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It returns this when run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Gilliane\Downloads\bsdiff4.3-win32\bspatch.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
```

I've done some browsing around, and know that in C#, you can request elevation by doing this, (as seen from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically)):

```
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

However, I don't see anything like that with ProcessBuilder.  Another method would be to have the [Elevation Tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.06.elevation.aspx) installed on the target system, and to invoke the "elevate" prompt with ProcessBuilder.  However, I would rather not force the people who use my program to also install those elevation tools.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can't be done with ProcessBuilder, you will need to call Windows API.

I've used [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) to achieve this with code similar to the following:

`Shell32X.java`:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.WString;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Shell32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HINSTANCE;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEY;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;

public interface Shell32X extends Shell32
{
    Shell32X INSTANCE = (Shell32X)Native.loadLibrary("shell32", Shell32X.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);

    int SW_HIDE = 0;
    int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
    int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;
    int SW_RESTORE = 9;
    int SW_SHOW = 5;
    int SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10;
    int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
    int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
    int SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7;
    int SW_SHOWNA = 8;
    int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
    int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;

    /** File not found. */
    int SE_ERR_FNF = 2;

    /** Path not found. */
    int SE_ERR_PNF = 3;

    /** Access denied. */
    int SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED = 5;

    /** Out of memory. */
    int SE_ERR_OOM = 8;

    /** DLL not found. */
    int SE_ERR_DLLNOTFOUND = 32;

    /** Cannot share an open file. */
    int SE_ERR_SHARE = 26;



    int SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS = 0x00000040;


    int ShellExecute(int i, String lpVerb, String lpFile, String lpParameters, String lpDirectory, int nShow);
    boolean ShellExecuteEx(SHELLEXECUTEINFO lpExecInfo);



    public static class SHELLEXECUTEINFO extends Structure
    {
        /*
  DWORD     cbSize;
  ULONG     fMask;
  HWND      hwnd;
  LPCTSTR   lpVerb;
  LPCTSTR   lpFile;
  LPCTSTR   lpParameters;
  LPCTSTR   lpDirectory;
  int       nShow;
  HINSTANCE hInstApp;
  LPVOID    lpIDList;
  LPCTSTR   lpClass;
  HKEY      hkeyClass;
  DWORD     dwHotKey;
  union {
    HANDLE hIcon;
    HANDLE hMonitor;
  } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
  HANDLE    hProcess;
         */

        public int cbSize = size();
        public int fMask;
        public HWND hwnd;
        public WString lpVerb;
        public WString lpFile;
        public WString lpParameters;
        public WString lpDirectory;
        public int nShow;
        public HINSTANCE hInstApp;
        public Pointer lpIDList;
        public WString lpClass;
        public HKEY hKeyClass;
        public int dwHotKey;

        /*
         * Actually:
         * union {
         *  HANDLE hIcon;
         *  HANDLE hMonitor;
         * } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
         */
        public HANDLE hMonitor;
        public HANDLE hProcess;

        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList(new String[] {
                "cbSize", "fMask", "hwnd", "lpVerb", "lpFile", "lpParameters",
                "lpDirectory", "nShow", "hInstApp", "lpIDList", "lpClass",
                "hKeyClass", "dwHotKey", "hMonitor", "hProcess",
            });
        }
    }

}
```

`Elevator.java`:

```
package test;

import test.Shell32X.SHELLEXECUTEINFO;

import com.sun.jna.WString;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32Util;

public class Elevator
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        executeAsAdministrator("c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe", "");
    }

    public static void executeAsAdministrator(String command, String args)
    {
        Shell32X.SHELLEXECUTEINFO execInfo = new Shell32X.SHELLEXECUTEINFO();
        execInfo.lpFile = new WString(command);
        if (args != null)
            execInfo.lpParameters = new WString(args);
        execInfo.nShow = Shell32X.SW_SHOWDEFAULT;
        execInfo.fMask = Shell32X.SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
        execInfo.lpVerb = new WString("runas");
        boolean result = Shell32X.INSTANCE.ShellExecuteEx(execInfo);

        if (!result)
        {
            int lastError = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError();
            String errorMessage = Kernel32Util.formatMessageFromLastErrorCode(lastError);
            throw new RuntimeException("Error performing elevation: " + lastError + ": " + errorMessage + " (apperror=" + execInfo.hInstApp + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I'll test this in the scope of my application and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the confirmation pop up (run as admin) by using something in the code?

Comment: I was reluctant to try this one out - because I don't understand the code - but it works perfectly. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: @user1813222 what did you do? I get no classDefFound error

Comment: This is not a replacement for ProcessBuilder, because it doesn't take into account the Working Directory...

Comment: @marcolopes the working directory can be set through [SHELLEXECUTEINFO's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfoa) lpDirectory.

Answer (score 0):

[Prunge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11042773/4254056)'s answer works fine for me.But after doing a bit more research ,I found out another approach using vb script and batch file.I prefer this approach because using vb-script does not cause black cmd window to pop up every time,when I open my application.

1. Create an ordinary bat file to open the external executable file.
   I am going to open a MySQL server executable file

   ```
   @echo off
   cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
   :: Title not needed:
   start /MIN  mysqld.exe
   exit
   ```
2. Save it as mysql.bat
3. Now create a vb script with admin privileges and at the end add script to open mysql.bat file.

At the end  CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run runs the bat file mysql.bat.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")'
 If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
    Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
    WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
    " RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
    Wscript.Quit
    End if
    CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "C:\Users\Shersha\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Berries\batch\mysql.bat",0,True
```

4. Now save this file as mysql_start.vbs
5. Finally Run vb script from java .

Thats it

```
 try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript C:\\\\Users\\\\Shersha\\\\Documents\\\\NetBeansProjects\\\\Berries\\\\batch\\\\mysql_start.vbs");
        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println(e);
                            System.exit(0);
        }
```