# How to start java program (from .jar) elevated only using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, jar, uac

There is a [great answer providing a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12264592/607407) what will allways do it's best to run elevated and will not elevate if already elevated.

I don't want to distribute the batch file with my program though. The whole core of the answer is this VBSScript:

```
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
UAC.ShellExecute "[path to the batch file which will run elevated]", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1
```

Pretty simple. So just instead of the path to the batch file, I want to use the path to a jar file. But it doesn't seem to work:

```
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
UAC.ShellExecute "AutoClient.jar", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1
```

[image: **Error:** There is no program associated with this file to perform the operation. Install a program or, if already installed one, create an association control panel "preselectable programs. "]

```
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
UAC.ShellExecute "javaw -jar AutoClient.jar", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1
```

[image: Windows cannot find javaw -jar AutoClient.jar. Make sure you typed the name correctly.]

```
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
UAC.ShellExecute "javaw", "ELEV", "-jar AutoClient.jar", "runas", 1
```

[image: image description]

So well, how can I run the jar from the vbs file? Both files share the same directory. It's necessary that java application's working directory is **that** directory.

**Edit:**
So thanks @MCND (and [this](http://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html)) I now know that the arguments go as follows:

```
path to executable to run
command line parameters sent to the program
working directory of the new process
'runas' command which invokes elevation
0 means do not show the window, 1 to show the window
```

And thanks to his code:

```
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
UAC.ShellExecute "javaw.exe", "-jar AutoClient.jar", "", "runas", 1
```

I can add another error in my collection:

[image: image description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the only way I made this work without crazy popup errors is:

```
' Get the script location, the directorry where it's running
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 

' Args:
'   path to executable to run
'   command line parameters - first parameter of this file, which is the jar file name
'   working directory (this doesn't work but I use it nevertheless)
'   runas command which invokes elevation
'   0 means do not show the window. Normally, you show the window, but not this console window
'     which just blinks and disappears anyway
UAC.ShellExecute "run-normally.bat", "SomeFile.jar, strFolder, "runas", 0
```

Because the working directory parameter doesn't work, I have following two lines in the bat file:

```
rem Used as a helper for the elevating VBS script. Runs the jar file
rem given as 1st argument as if the file was double clicked.

rem Make sure we're on our CURRENT directory
cd /d %~dp0
rem Run java, expecting the jar file to be given as the 1st argument
javaw -jar %1
```

I am not satisfied with this solution for cosmetic reasons. I want to display the UAC message for JRE, not windows command line:

[image: image description]

Comment: I don't use Java but you aren't specifing full paths. You can't expect things to work reliably. Also whatever you are starting will need to have on it's right click menu Run As Administrator because the VBS code runs that menu command as if you clicked it. If it's not there you can't click it. EXE have it. So specify the correct paths to both Javaw and the jar file.

Comment: @Trigger path to `javaw.exe` is system dependent.

Comment: Exactly. So you need to do something. See filter for a batch file where I go to great lengths to find myself (https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E2F0CE17A268A4FA!121). But the main problem is the jar file, you are **hoping** it is in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that the first parameter in the call is the file to start, leaving the arguments to the second parameter. So it should be (sorry, not tested)

```vbscript
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
UAC.ShellExecute "javaw.exe", "-jar AutoClient.jar", "", "runas", 1
```

Comment: I am sorry, but this one throws error too. I added it in my question. I managed to make this work using intermediate `.bat` file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Java but you aren't specifing full paths. You can't expect things to work reliably. Also whatever you are starting will need to have on it's right click menu Run As Administrator because the VBS code runs that menu command as if you clicked it. If it's not there you can't click it. EXE have it. So specify the correct paths to both Javaw and the jar file.

One issue is that the current directory is different depending on what technique you are using. ALWAYS specify full paths.

Here's a script that lists what verbs are available for an object (not we are not working with files but with objects). The graphical shell (explorer) is an object browser and has no idea what a file is apart from the fact it's an object of some type.

```
---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------

  ShVerb

  Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder

    ShVerb <filename> [verb]

  Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder

  The program lists most verbs but only ones above the first separator
  of the menu work when used this way

  The Properties verb can be used. However the program has to keep running
  to hold the properties dialog open. It keeps running by displaying
  a message box.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

The script

```
HelpMsg = vbcrlf & "  ShVerb" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  David Candy 2014" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder" & vbcrlf  & vbcrlf & "    ShVerb <filename> [verb]" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The program lists most verbs but only ones above the first separator" & vbcrlf & "  of the menu work when used this way" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf 
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The Properties verb can be used. However the program has to keep running" & vbcrlf & "  to hold the properties dialog open. It keeps running by displaying" & vbcrlf & "  a message box." 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag = WScript.Arguments 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Ag.count = 0 then 
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - No file specified"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    Else If Ag.count = 1 then 
        If LCase(Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/")) = "/h" or Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/") = "/?" then 
            wscript.echo HelpMsg 
            wscript.quit
        End If
    ElseIf Ag.count > 2 then 
        wscript.echo vbcrlf & "  ShVerb - To many parameters" & vbcrlf & "  Use quotes around filenames and verbs containing spaces"  & vbcrlf
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    If fso.DriveExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
'       Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.self
        msgbox ag(0)
    ElseIf fso.FolderExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    ElseIf fso.fileExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    Else
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - " & Ag(0) & " not found"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    Set objVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs

    'If only one argument list verbs for that item

    If Ag.count = 1 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If len(cmd) <> 0 then CmdList = CmdList & vbcrlf & replace(cmd.name, "&", "") 
        Next
        wscript.echo mid(CmdList, 2)

    'If two arguments do verbs for that item

    ElseIf Ag.count = 2 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If lcase(replace(cmd, "&", "")) = LCase(Ag(1)) then 
                wscript.echo(Cmd.doit)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    'Properties is special cased. Script has to stay running for Properties dialog to show.
        If Lcase(Ag(1)) = "properties" then
            WSHShell.AppActivate(ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties")
            msgbox "This message box has to stay open to keep the " & ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties dialog open."
        End If  
    End If
End If
```