# How do you run commands with admin privileges?

Tags: java, command-prompt

How do you run a command using cmd (Windows 10) in java, using admin privileges, but without opening the program with admin privileges.

For example I would want to run a command like **shutdown /i**, this command does not need admin privileges but others I may run will.

Comment: Windows? Which "program"? Do you have "runas"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elevate Java application while running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082838/elevate-java-application-while-running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, `runas` (run as ... ) allows you to run a program under another account.
Just `runas` at a prompt for help.
For exmaple

```
runas /env /user:user@domain.microsoft.com "notepad \"my file.txt\""
```

You need quotes and uote escaping for parameters.
but basically, **runas who/where** then **your command**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo` as a prefix before any command you run.

Comment: This is for Linux or Mac OS.
You could use runas for win - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx or sudowin - http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/