# Java elevate with JNA

Tags: uac, jna

hi i was following a this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11042773/2665500? but i cant make it work???

when i try and compile it, i says that

```
public static class SHELLEXECUTEINFO extends Structure
```

needs to be abstract... but if i make it abstract then wont init?

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO execInfo = new SHELLEXECUTEINFO();
```

what do i need to change to get this to elevate a process??

thanks

Comment: To make a Java subclass non-abstract, you need to implement the abstract methods in the abstract base class.

Comment: ok will give it a go thanks..... by changing public abstract class Structure... without the abstract

Comment: ok that didnt work either... im not used to changing other code just adding it in....... is there a specific line i need to change?

Comment: You need to implement the "missing" abstract method [`getFieldOrder()`](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/StructuresAndUnions.md).Your class *should not* be abstract.

Comment: yeah i tryed that also but i have never used or done this before and not sure what is actually needed....     protected abstract List getFieldOrder(); that is what is in the Structure class how do i implement it? i dont know what to put in it???    @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {}

Comment: Review the [`getFieldOrder()` implementation in the original example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041509/elevating-a-processbuilder-process-via-uac/11042773#11042773).

Comment: OMG!! yes thanks so much how did i miss that... thanks...