# Elevate process with UAC java

Tags: java, uac, processbuilder

I need to install a windows service from inside my Java application. I have a `bat` file, that does that. Thing is, it needs elevation.

How can I *easily* do that from my Java code?

I've looked here: [Elevating a ProcessBuilder process via UAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041509/elevating-a-processbuilder-process-via-uac) and it seems like a freakishly large code for such a simple operation. Is there an easier way? That thread is 3 y.o., so maybe something happend since then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start your application with elevated permissions it should do the trick from what I remember.

The alternative is that you wrap the bat file in say an exe that has a manifest file that requires elevated permissions. This will prompt the UAC.

See this SO post about creating bat files with elevated permissions.
[Elevating batch permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-administrator)

Comment: My application is deployed to Tomcat, so... How about a manifest for bat file? Can I do that?

Comment: You could still wrap the bat file in an exe that tomcat calls, but I have edited my answer to point to a SO question about elevating batch file permissions.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-administrator

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you could also do this with a shortcut, using the option to run the target as an administrator.