# Running Java ProcessBuilder in elevated mode

Tags: java, processbuilder

How can I run the java ProcessBuilder in elevated mode/Admin mode for executing commands similarly like we open command prompt as admin and run some commands?
Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041509/elevating-a-processbuilder-process-via-uac

Comment: @andrucz - I saw this post but seems to be different way and bit complex. Still trying to look if it can be achieved using processbuilder itself

Comment: I still haven't found a "simple" solution. It seems like doesn't exist. Take a look at http://mark.koli.ch/uac-prompt-from-java-createprocess-error740-the-requested-operation-requires-elevation